# Change agent size presentation throughout the model

Tags: anylogic

I'm building different size modules and I want to reflect that in my simulation run presentation aspect. I have the parameters set (height, width, length) on the agent but it wouldn't change when I run the simulation. The first image shows how it is now but I want it to look like the second image [I read the anylogic help but its not very helpful.](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_Material%2Freference%2FItem_Dimensions.html) Where is a good source to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is really hard to understand. Please clarify and explain what you did, what the problem is... Check this help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to rephrase it and added some pictures. Thanks!

Comment: and how did you setup the source properties? If you set a static value for height/width... then obviously, each agent will use it. You need to give individual agents individual values.